# How to increase the output current of LM7805

Tags: voltage-regulator

I wanted to make a solar powered charger for my phone but the current is too low and will cause charging to be slow. So i wanted to ask is there any ways to increase the output current to 2A?

Comment: user another regulator that can deliver more

Comment: The output voltage i need is 5V. Is there any regulator that its output is 5V 2A?

Comment: there are likely many

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Other than using the high current circuit described in the datasheet?

Comment: can i just install a heat sink on the regulator?

Comment: At least *pretend* to look.

Comment: This now turns into a shopping question and those are **Off topic**. Anyway, instead of an LM7805 or variant, use a **switched** regulator module as this will not get warm so you will not need a heatsink. I suggest an LM2596 based module: for example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2596-DC-DC-4V-35V-to-1-23V-30V-Step-Down-Power-Module-Voltage-Regulator-3A-/251066005460  It has a trimmer (blue thingy), you turn it to 5 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Photon has already answered your question directly.  While that answer is correct, it is not what I recommend.

As The Photon points out, the minimum input voltage of a 7805 with additional pass transistor is probably around 8 V.  That means with 2 A output, the whole setup will dissipate a *minimum* of 6 W.  That's a lot of heat to get rid of.  Most likely you'll end up running the regulator with more than 8 V in.  That results in even more heat to get rid of.

The solution is to use a buck switcher.  That will be more efficient, work with lower input voltage, and not dissipate significantly more with higher input voltage.  You want 2 A at 5 V out, so 10 W.  A buck switcher that is 85% efficient would only dissipate 1.8 W.  That will be distributed between several parts, so you probably don't need a heat sink.  Due to no heat sink, the result will be smaller and cheaper.

Comment: In fact, that's the only way to get higher output current than input current, which is what the OP is actually asking for.

Comment: Can the buck switcher be built by using a LM7805 IC?

Comment: @Pha: I don't know off the top of my head.  Look at its datasheet and see.

Comment: @Olin: Is there another name for buck switcher? Because i cant seem to find a circuit named buck switcher in the fairchild datasheet for LM7805

Comment: @Pha: "Buck converter", "switching power supply" with higher input voltage than output voltage, and probably a few others.

Comment: i found L78S05CV which has an output of 5V and 2A.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 7805 regulator can be used to control an external pass transistor. Many 7805 datasheets show this as an example application circuit. Here's the example from the Fairchild datasheet:

[image]

The drawback is that this increases the dropout voltage --- you may need 8 V input to get 5 V out, rather than the 7 V you'd need for the 7805 alone. Both the 7805 and the external transistor may need heat-sinks.

Before actually building this, you might want to consider what your circuit should do if there is not enough solar energy available to provide 2A at 8 V to the input, and design appropriate precautions.

**Edit:** As has been pointed out in the comments, a linear solution like this one requires the solar panel be able to produce 2 A at the regulator input voltage (8 V-ish). Be sure your solar panel is able to do that with the available lighting conditions.

A switching regulator solution (such as is presented in another answer) can produce more output current than input current, but still must obey conservation of energy (power out < power in).

Comment: Also worth noting that the external pass transistor will not benefit from the 7805's temperature and short circuit protection.

Comment: You answered the question in the title, but not the one in the body of the post. The OP wants to boost the current available at 5V beyond what's available from the solar panel, and the only way to do that is with a switchmode converter.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I don't see where he says the solar panel isn't producing enough current (although I agree it's possible that's what's happening).